# Ajax js syntax with ruby variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Im trying to toggle a button without refreshing using ajax

In my micropost_helper.rb

```
def toggle_like_button(micropost, user)
  if user.voted_for?(micropost)
    link_to "undo", like_micropost_path(micropost), :class => "btn btn-mini btn-primary", :id =>"unvote_form_#{micropost.id}", :remote => true
  else
    link_to "Into it!", like_micropost_path(micropost), :class => "btn btn-mini btn-primary", :id =>"vote_form_#{micropost.id}", :remote => true
  end
end
```

In microposts/like.js.erb

```
$("#vote_form_#{@micropost.id}").html("undo")
$("#unvote_form_#{@micropost.id}").html("Into it!")
```

I think the syntax is messed up. the `#{@micropost.id}` part is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
$("#vote_form_#{@micropost.id}").html("undo")
$("#unvote_form_#{@micropost.id}").html("Into it!")
```

with

```
$("#vote_form_<%=@micropost.id}%>").html("undo");
$("#unvote_form_<%=@micropost.id}%>").html("Into it!");
```

Comment: you meant $("#vote_form_<%=@micropost.id%>").html("undo")
$("#unvote_form_<%=@micropost.id%>").html("Into it!") but thanks!